# display: inline-block DIV pushed downward

Tags: html, css

Why the second `DIV` when using `display: inline-block` is pushing downward?

Here is my code what I have tried.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
}
.div2{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #00F;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/fbreJ/

I know that it works using `float: left`, but I can't use it in what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's the way `inline-block` elements work.

To *fix* that, just add a vertical aligment:

```
.div2 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**jsFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/fbreJ/1/